# How to change appearance of "position: sticky" element ONLY when the user starts scrolling and its stickiness becomes apparent?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some very simple CSS code that makes one particular div container "sticky", and when the user scrolls down, that div element stays locked at the top of the screen as expected.

I am trying to figure out how to make it so the sticky element in question CHANGES APPEARANCE the instant the user scrolls down and the "stickiness" of this element becomes clear? Maybe when it hits the top of the parent container, maybe just when the user scrolls past a certain point -- there might be several ways to code this, but I can't seem to figure out any.

Specifically what I want to do is -- add a bottom border of 1px when they start scrolling and the sticky element follows. Until then, have the border be invisible/not there.

Note also that I read borders cause weird problems with sticky elements, and that shadows are a workaround for this, so I'm currently doing this for the "border":

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 #000000, inset 0 -1px 0 #000000;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the length of the page they're scrolling will continually change -- so setting it to change when they scroll a certain percent might not work well, since the page length will be dynamically changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put your style in a class and toggle this class in your HTML

```
//Simply with jQuery
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
      $('.element').addClass('your_class_name');
   } else {
      $('.element').removeClass('your_class_name');
   }
});

//With JavaScript
window.onscroll = function() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 150 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 150) {
    document.querySelector(".element").classList.add("your_class_name");
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".element").classList.remove("your_class_name");
  }
};
```

This will add `class` if user scrolled over `150px`

Comment: Clean. Works like a charm. Slightly modified it to use GetElementByID instead of querySelector. One question. I set scroll position to 215, because that's perfect for making it appear at the right moment. Will this position vary based on the user's computer screen size etc? Meaning, could 215 for me end up functionally being 310 for someone else, 155 for another person? Or is that a consistent metric regardless of screen size? It's for a Chrome Extension, if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: One more question: Any way to animate/fade the transition between the two? As it currently is, it's kind of abrupt. A subtle transition period would make it SUPER clean. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I added this to the class that contains the border shadow, and it works to delay the application of that class change. So it fades in nicely vs. appearing abruptly. Very cool stuff! Thanks for the help, Mohamed. -- transition: ease all .3s;

Comment: It's just `215px` and it will not change for each different screen size but, the other HTML element could be change their size `responsive` such as `img` so the class still added after `215px` but you may see it in different location of page

Comment: ` transition: ease all .3s` is a very good solution in this case, If this answer worked perfectly please mark it as an answer to guide others

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using IntersectionObserver for this. The downside to the scroll-based approach? MAYBE in some cases? If the sizes of elements adjust dynamically/responsively based on screen size, browser being used, etc? It could cause the change to be made at the wrong moment, which could look really bad. IntersectionObserver appears to consistent make the change based on the relative position of the sticky element and the parent div -- so it SHOULD be consistent across all use cases.

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-detect-when-a-sticky-element-gets-pinned/